# WooCommerce Thermal Receipt Print displays HTML tags

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, thermal-printer, strip-tags

I am trying to integrate a thermal printer with WooCommerce. Prints for Simple Products come fine but for Variable Products, print displays HTML Tags.

[image]

I tried stirp_tags in a snippet but the result displays no products at all in the receipt. Though the rest of the fields are fine. Can anyone with better coding skills check if the code is fine?

```
    add_filter( 'before_send_order_to_iconnect', 'printer_tags_strip' );
function printer_tags_strip($object){
$order_info = new WC_Order($object->order_id);
$order = $object;
$order->item = strip_tags($order_info, '<br>');
return $order; }
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Best regards.

Comment: the issue with `&quote`

Answer (score 0):

In your code issue is `&quote` Use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

```
add_filter( 'before_send_order_to_iconnect', 'printer_tags_strip' );
function printer_tags_strip($object){
    $order_info = new WC_Order($object->order_id);
    $order = $object;
    $order_info = htmlspecialchars_decode($order_info, ENT_QUOTES); // Converts double and single quotes
    $order->item = strip_tags($order_info, '<br>');
    return $order; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The result is still coming empty without any products.

Comment: Worked out the working code.

add_filter( 'before_send_order_to_iconnect', 'printer_tags_strip' );

function printer_tags_strip($object){

    $order = $object;

    $items = array();
    foreach ($order->item as $item){
       $item->Category = strip_tags($item->Category, '<br>');
       $item->Description = strip_tags($item->Description, '<br>');
       $item->Item = strip_tags($item->Item, '<br>');
       array_push($items, $item);
    }
    $order->item = $items;
    return $order;
}